# laravel bulk sms notification sending

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

hello I'm new for laravel I'm trying to send SMS notification from api.

I'm using 3rd party service for sending sms thy have less documentation for php code integration. and API URL

When I tried in laravel form controller when form submit sms notification will triggers by this
but problem is my API User name and passwords displayed in browser URL and inspect network tab too is was problem I don't want to show my API Credentials to any one

```
return redirect()->away("http://api.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=....&password=.......&mobile=........&message=hello&sender=.......&type=3&template_id=123");
```

** php code integration service provider document**

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$username="XXXXXXX";
$password ="XXXXXXX";
$number=$_POST['number'];
$sender="abc";
$message=$_POST['message'];
$template_id='12345';
if($_POST['submitted']=='true')
{ 
$url="http://api.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=".urlencode($username)."&password=".urlencode($password)."&mobile=".urlencode($number)."&sender=".urlencode($sender)."&message=".urlencode($message)."&type=".urlencode('3')."&template_id=".urlencode($template_id);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
}

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="sms_gate" >
<br />
Number : <br />
<input type="text" name="number" />
<br /><br />
Message:<br/>
<textarea name="message" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

** API URL code integration service provider document provided this**

```
URL : http://api.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=....&password=.......&mobile=........&message=hello&sender=.......&type=3&template_id=123
```

**my controller**

```
public function Store_Enrollment(Request $request)

    {

      $this->validate($request, [

  'student_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'student_phone_no' => 'required|string|max:10',
         
    ]);
 
   $input['student_name'] = ucfirst ($request['student_name']);
   $input['student_phone_no'] = $request->student_phone_no;
   $redirect = Student::create($input); 
 
  
return redirect()->away("http://api.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=XXX&password=XXX&mobile=$redirect->student_phone_no&message=Dear  $redirect->student_name,  G&sender=ABC&type=3&template_id=112"); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIs like this are intended to be called server-to-server, not in the browser.

You can use the [Laravel HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) to make a call to this API from your server; this will not expose the API keys or other sensitive data.

Comment: can you give help me to implement in controller any demo plz

Comment: @user12380208 I would encourage you to read the linked documentation. It's a very simple system.

Comment: i used this it was worked i need to know is this not showing any data in inspect or browser  $response = Http::post("http://api.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=XXX&password=XXX&mobile=$redirect->student_phone_no&message=Dear  $redirect->student_name,  G&sender=ABC&type=3&template_id=112");

Comment: Correct, that would not show up in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use Laravel Trait and guzzlehttp/guzzle Package to send bulk sms.
The steps I did was something like below

i) I installed guzzlehttp/guzzle Package. Associated documentation is https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client.

ii) I created Laravel trait class. Inside the trait class, I write a method to send SMS. I use CURL to call the third party SMS API.

iii) In the controller I import the Trait class and call the SMS sending trait method from there.

I hope this steps help.